# Does Python asyncio use a thread pool?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I wrote this bit of code:

```
import asyncio
import threading
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            response = await response.read()
            print(threading.current_thread().name)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch("http://example.com")) for i in range(5)]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

It prints out "MainThread" every time. Does this mean that all of the requests are being executed concurrently using the same main thread and it's not using threads from a thread pool to execute each request or are the threads being abstracted?

This post seems to show that in fact there is a thread pool which Python uses for these async tasks:
http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> It prints out "MainThread" every time. Does this mean that all of the requests are being executed concurrently using the same main thread and it's not using threads from a thread pool to execute each request or are the threads being abstracted?

It's not using worker threads, `asyncio` will only use the main thread.  Concurrency is achieved through cooperative multitasking by using Python generators (read about [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)).

> This post seems to show that in fact there is a thread pool ...

As well as `asyncio` module, the blog post you linked explicitly uses the `concurrent.futures` module.  The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class from that code will spawn worker threads.  But the example code in your question will not.