# How can Flask rest endpoint communicate to a pyqt application running on the same python program

Tags: python, flask, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to create a simple rest endpoint, that when hit, it changes the status of a tray icon that is installed by the program itself.

I believe that I need Flask and the QApplication to run in different threads and I tried to do this.

However I am not familiar with python and most probably I am doing something wrong below:

```py
import sys
import asyncio
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QSystemTrayIcon, 
    QApplication, 
    QWidget
    )
from flask import Flask 



async def gui():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("disconnected.png"), w)
    trayIcon.show()        
    print("running gui")
    return app.exec()


async def rest():
    app1 = Flask(__name__) 
    
    @app1.route("/status/connected") 
    def setStatusConnected(): 
        return "I will signal gui to change icon to connected"
    @app1.route("/status/disconnected") 
    def setStatusDisconnected(): 
        return "I will signal gui to change icon to disconnected"

    print("creating rest endpoint")
    return app1.run()  



async def main():
    return await asyncio.gather(gui(), rest() )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run the code above I see only "running gui" and I can see the tray icon being installed to the status bar. I do not see "creating rest endpoint"

If I comment-out the "return app.exec()". I see the "creating rest endpoint" and I can access the endpoints, but I don't see the the tray icon.

Whay is am I missing?

extra info: this is my `Pipfile` (Using `pipenv`)

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pyqt6 = "*"
flask = {extras = ["async"], version = "*"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

Comment: Research more. You are misunderstanding the architecture of the asyncio. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427807/1186624). A plain normal Qt and Flask event loop as shown in your code does not support the asyncio event loop. Just use the standard ```threading``` library.

Comment: `Flask` and `Qt` don't use `await` inside its code so `asyncio` is useless

Answer (score 1):

Following [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) answer I provide a working solution of running both `flask` and `pyqt` app that installs a system tray icon with the ability to update the icon status based on received rest requests:

- used threading instead of asyncio
- used a `Qtimer` inside gui that checks every second a mutable variable set by rest endpoint and updates

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from threading import Thread
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QSystemTrayIcon, 
    QApplication, 
    QWidget
    )
from flask import Flask 

class MutableValue:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v
event = MutableValue('disconnected')

def gui():
    def iconFromValue(value):
        return QIcon(value+".png");
    def checkStatus():
        #TODO: check if value changed before applying icon
        trayIcon.setIcon(iconFromValue(event.value)) 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # timer to check every second for an update from rest
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(checkStatus)
    timer.start(1000)
    w = QWidget()
    trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(iconFromValue(event.value), w)
    trayIcon.show()
    print("running gui..")
    return app.exec()


def rest():
    app1 = Flask(__name__) 
    
    @app1.route("/status/connected") 
    def setStatusConnected(): 
        event.value='connected'
        return "Changed status to connected."
        
    @app1.route("/status/disconnected") 
    def setStatusDisconnected(): 
        event.value='disconnected'
        return "Changed status to disconnected."
    print("creating rest endpoint..")
    return app1.run()  



def main():
    g=Thread(target=gui, daemon=True)
    r=Thread(target=rest, daemon=True)
    
    g.start()
    r.start()
    g.join()
    r.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

`ayncio` is useful when programs uses `await` inside its code - inside `app.run()` and inside `app.exec()` - but as I know `Qt` and `Flask` don't do this. (but maybe `Flask` has version which uses `asyncio`)

You may need to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to run programs in separated threads (or one program run in separated thread and other run in current thread).

Version 1: both programs in separated threads

```
def gui(): # without `async
    #...

def rest(): # without `async
    #...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from threading import Thread
    
    t1 = Thread(target=gui)
    t2 = Thread(target=rest)
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    # it blocks this function and wait for end of threads
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Version 2: one programs in separated thread and other in current thread

```
def gui(): # without `async
    #...

def rest(): # without `async
    #...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from threading import Thread
    
    t1 = Thread(target=gui)
    t1.start()

    rest() # it blocks this function

    # wait for end of thread
    t1.join()
```

---

Full working code

```
import sys
import asyncio
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QSystemTrayIcon, 
    QApplication, 
    QWidget
    )
from flask import Flask 


def gui():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    w = QWidget()
    trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("disconnected.png"), w)
    trayIcon.show()        
    
    print("running gui")
    
    app.exec()


def rest():
    app = Flask(__name__) 
    
    @app.route("/connect") 
    def connect(): 
        return "I will signal gui to change icon to connected"
        
    @app.route("/disconnect") 
    def disconnect(): 
        return "I will signal gui to change icon to disconnected"

    print("creating rest endpoint")
    
    app.run()  


def version_1():
    from threading import Thread
    
    t1 = Thread(target=gui)
    t2 = Thread(target=rest)
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    # it blocks this function and wait for end of threads
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

def version_2()
    from threading import Thread
    
    t1 = Thread(target=gui)
    t1.start()

    rest() # it blocks this function

    # wait for end of thread
    t1.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #version_1()
    version_2()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I not sure if these threads may use Qt signals to communicates. They may need to use [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to comunicate, and `Qt` may need `QTimer` to check periodically if there is new information in `queue`.

Other idea: `Flask` should have `url` which returns current status (information if it is connected or disconnected) and `Qt` could use `QTime` with probably `QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))` to check this status. This way you can always use other GUI framework to check status. Or you can check status in text console (ie. using `curl`, `wget`)

If you plan to use `Flask` only to change status in `Qt` then maybe you should use `QtNetwork` to run server directly in `Qt` without using `Flask`.

Comment: Indeed it worked by using `Thread`. Yes I plan to only change status via rest. Actually I want a simple bash command to be able to easily provide an always-visible status indication to the tray icon (e.g. vpnstatus-isConnected/isDisconnected). So I will check `QtNetwork` as you said. Now to communicate from rest to gui I used: `sig = pyqtBoundSignal()`  (`pyqtSignal()` does not have `connect() / emit()` on `pyqt6`. Not sure if I picked the correct method though). But with that I get a `Segmentation fault` when I call `sig.connect(someHandler)` from `gui()` or `sig.emit()` from flask rest.

Comment: FYI: Provided an answer with a working solution, based on your feedback. Did not use queue because I considered that If I had to use a timer also for it to work, it would be more preferable to use only the timer.